# Disable modal for small screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to disable / desactived modal for a small screen.
I tried to use `Class="hidden-xs"`with Bootstrap, this desactive my modal but block my screen.

My Html :

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <p class="titre">Nature morte à l'écrevisse</p>
        <img src="img/1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Peinture à huile clair obscur"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog" >
            <div class="modal-dialog" >
              <div class="modal-content"style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;border-style: none; box-shadow: none;">
                    <h4 style="color: white !important;">Nature morte à l'écrevisse</h4>
                    <img src="img/1.jpg" class="" style="width:100%;" alt="Peinture à huile clair obscur">
                    <p style="color: white !important;">150x120 cm avec cadre -  A Vendre</p>
              </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

I would like to disable / erase the code below for a small screen :

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog" >
            <div class="modal-dialog" >
              <div class="modal-content"style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;border-style: none; box-shadow: none;">
                    <h4 style="color: white !important;">Nature morte à l'écrevisse</h4>
                    <img src="img/1.jpg" class="" style="width:100%;" alt="Peinture à huile clair obscur">
                    <p style="color: white !important;">150x120 cm avec cadre -  A Vendre</p>
              </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
```

With CSS or maybe in JavaScript ?

Any help or tips would be appreciate :)

EDIT 1 :

I have this script in my code, maybe it's not a good version ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This is the link of my website : https://www.vmbringer.fr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an event handler to the modal show event (`show.bs.modal`).
The modal will not show if you return `false` from the event handler, so you can check the user agent and return false if the agent matches.

```
$(".modal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    e.preventDefault();//Works from Bootstrap 3.0.0
    return false;
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

This is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tmvj7xk9/

In the fiddle i have used width for mobile detection, because it's easier for testing purposes.

**EDIT 2**

According to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#js-events), from version 3.0.0 all infinitive bootstrap events provide `preventDefault` functionality. This provides the ability to stop the execution of an action before it starts.

**EDIT 3**
Another way of preventing the modal is to add a listener on click on the triggering element, and cancel the event there.

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() < 900) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But this function simply returns, but does not cancels other events that shows modal

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't show the modal if the event handler returns false. I'll try to privide a JSFiddle

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for me. I tried ".modal" or "#mymodal1". I put the code in my header in the balise `script`. I don't know why this doesn't work.

Comment: I've added an alternate method

Comment: Thanks again, but it doesn't work. I think I do a mistake, I added the link of my website, could you check please ? I'm very thankfull !

Comment: I'll try the script on your HTML to understand why it doesn't work

Comment: You have to wrap the js script that uses jQuery in documentReady, i'll update the code snippet

Answer (score 2):

Try using `show.bs.modal` event to cancel modal showing:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if ($(window).height() < 970) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).modal('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for me. Do you have any ideas of why ? I had edit my post with more explication